# Make text box stop growing after sm break point?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 input text box. I want make it stop growing after sm break point, so that it won't expand to the full screen width.

Comment: share your code

Comment: It's a plain form inside div with container class . Used bootstrap row class as well

Comment: but we have to show your code for helping you

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-md-*` in `wrap` div of input...

the `sm` takes all screen and from `md` and up it takes `width` as you set in `col-md-*`

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/s9q4d681/3/

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

input{
  max-width: 340px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Col-6
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Col-6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can simply restrict input field width using `max-width` CSS property.